# SSO and Functional Directory AD LDS

Tags: forms-authentication, sso, ad-lds

I have Portal deployed on SharePoint Server 2013.

The authentication and authorization are managed in SharePoint with an AD LDS instance containing functional accounts 
(no link between the functional account and the account that the user uses to log on windows - his windows accounts defined in AD DS)

- the portal use an FBA authentication based on the AD LDS instance
- user and groups from the AD LDS instance are used to manage authorizations in the portal.

I would like to add a SSO authentication in the portal with the windows account.

When the user opens a windows session with his windows account, he is automatically logged into the SharePoint portal by SSO but I would like to make sure that the account used
in the portal is not the windows account but the functional account defined in the AD LDS instance (for that we should put  in the AD LDS user information the associated window accounts login)

(The SSO authentication shall remain optional. If the SSO authentication failed, the user is redirected to the form where he shall fill his AD LDS functional account login 
 and password)

Do you know if this kind of mechanism can be set up in SharePoint 2013 and if yes, in what way ?

Thanks a lot for your help !